# Want to display locale calendar's events

Tags: android

I'm new on android. I create a local calendar using content provider http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/. Now I want to display today's events in an activity. I create for this a cursor. Now I want to use this cursor to display events and I'm very limited. I need help, please!

Thanks!

```
public void readCalendarEvents(Context context) {

    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    Long beginTime=time.toMillis(false);
    time.set(59, 59, 23, time.monthDay, time.month, time.year);
    Long endTime=time.toMillis(false);

    String[] proj= new String[]{Instances._ID, Instances.TITLE, Instances.BEGIN, Instances.END, Instances.EVENT_ID};

    Cursor cursor = Instances.query(context.getContentResolver(), proj, beginTime, endTime);
}
```

I modify my code to return a cursor and this cursor will be used by a fragment to display the list of calendar's events. Can you verified these code for me? I get a nullPointerException on line: cursor = myCalendar.readCalendarEvents(getActivity());

Class of my cursor:

```
public Class MyCalendar{
public Cursor readCalendarEvents(Context context) {

    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    Long beginTime = time.toMillis(false);
    time.set(59, 59, 23, time.monthDay, time.month, time.year);
    Long endTime = time.toMillis(false);

    String[] proj = new String[] { Instances._ID, Instances.TITLE,
            Instances.BEGIN, Instances.END, Instances.EVENT_ID };

    Cursor cursor = Instances.query(context.getContentResolver(), proj,
            beginTime, endTime);


    return cursor;
```

}
}

and this is my fragment code:

```
public class ViewMyCalendarEvents extends Fragment{

private MyCalendar myCalendar;
private Cursor cursor;
private ListView listView;

public ViewMyCalendarEvents() {

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_list_events, container, false);


    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_events_list);

    cursor = myCalendar.readCalendarEvents(getActivity());

    final String[] fromColumns = { "title", "beginDate", "endDate" };

    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.fragment_list_events_items, cursor, fromColumns,
            new int[] { R.id.event_list_title, R.id.event_list_begin,
                    R.id.event_list_end }, 0);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Please try to better explain what the problem is you are facing.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to use an offline calendar to insert user's events. So I use this link : http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/ and I have successfully created the calendar. I can create and insert an event. Now I want to view my calendar's today's events  from an activity. Always with the link, I saw that I can create a cursor and use it to view events. the portion of my code show how I started to create cursor. Can you verified it if it's correct and how to use it to display a list of my calendar's events? I'm very new in android. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what's going on in the `Instances` class but other than that it looks good. Those methods like `insert()`, `query()` or `update()` are just a wrapper for SQL queries. Inform yourself about SQL and you won't have a problem with this.

Comment: How to use this cursor to display a list of events? thanks!

Comment: You can for example use a `CursorAdapter` to display the data in a `ListView`.